# Google cloud endpoints. auto_current_user_add and auto_current_user not a working

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-endpoints, endpoints-proto-datastore

I am using `endpoints_proto_datastore` library by dhermes in my project based on google-endpoints.

Here is my code

```
class Log(EndpointsModel):

    _message_fields_schema = ('id', 'createdOn', 'author', 'lastUpdatedBy')

    createdOn = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    author = ndb.UserProperty(auto_current_user_add=True)
    lastUpdatedBy = ndb.UserProperty(auto_current_user=True)


@endpoints.api(name="logs", version="v1", description="Logs API")
class LogsApi(remote.Service):
    @Log.method(user_required=True, path="log/create", name="create")
    def addLog(self, log):
    log.put()
    return log
```

when I call the API, I get the following response

```
{
    "createdOn": "2017-07-30T01:08:42.018641",
    "id": "6296903092273152"
}
```

Why are `auto_current_user_add` and `auto_current_user` property not working? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you calling your API?

Comment: I am using the Google API explorer.

Comment: Are you certain auth is being used? You may want to check that `endpoints.get_current_user() is not None`.

Comment: Yes auth is being used. I am using `endpoints.get_current_user().Email()` to get the email id.